# How to display entities on page? Getting instead [Entity of type ... with id: 1]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My objective is to display random texts from a database onto the a web page. Firstly, I don't know why my data aren't saved and why, instead of content I get [Entity of type sec.helloweb.HelloMessage with id: N].

How do I display the actual text/content of the class and not "Entity" on the web page?

### Controller

```
@Controller
public class HelloWebWithDatabaseController {

    @Autowired
    private HelloMessageRepository helloMessageRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String listAll(Model model) {

        HelloMessage mess = new HelloMessage();
        mess.setContent("lol");
        HelloMessage mes = new HelloMessage();
        mes.setContent("boo");
        helloMessageRepository.save(mes);
        helloMessageRepository.saveAndFlush(mess);
        model.addAttribute("message", helloMessageRepository.findAll());
        return "home";
    }
}
```

### HelloMessageRepository

```
package sec.helloweb;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface HelloMessageRepository extends JpaRepository<HelloMessage, Long> {

}
```

### HelloMessage

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Messages")
public class HelloMessage extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @Column(name = "Message")
    private String content;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

### Home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Message</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2 th:text="${message}">Testing</h2>    
        <p> This is testing ground</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XcFW.png

Comment: mark in tags (or code with imports etc) what exactly framework You use. A 'spring' is very broad description

Comment: in meritum You bind kind of collection to "message" (java) and use like simple object (html), efect is full clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message attribute contains a list, so in order to display each message content you need to iterate over the message list:

```
<h2 th:each="item : ${message}" th:text="${item.content}"></h2>
```

Comment: This was embarrassingly simple. But how can it be a list when it says "Entity"? Even if it is a list, why doesn't `model.addAttribute("message", helloMessageRepository.findAll()[0]);` work?

Comment: try get(0) not [0]